# Attach multiple files - Google Sheets/Gmail/Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I currently have a script to create draft emails and also attach a file to them. Currently, the script does not work for multiple file attachments and also does not work if there are no attachments.

Any tips on how to get (1) and (2) [below]

**Updated for more info:**

Main objective is to add a multiple file names in Col[3] and attaching the files to the draft using the files names provided in Col[3]. Example: if I type the following into Col[3]: "test.pdf, test2.pdf"
it will attach the files "test.pdf" & "test2.pdf" for that particular draft. 
At the moment, the script does attach a single file to a draft, but if I enter multiple file names separated by comas it does not create a draft at all.

I've attach a screenshot of how the spreadsheet looks like below when I run the script (I currently cannot embed pictures):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwuaM.jpg

When I run the script using the info from the screenshot, the 2nd row does not create a draft at all, the 3rd row creates a draft with the attachment and the 4th row does not create a draft at all.

Would it be possible to create a draft and attach multiple files using filenames separated by comas and also create drafts when some cells in Col[3] is empty?

**TLDR:**

1. How to attach multiple files to individual drafts
2. How to create a draft without any attachments

```js
function SaveDrafts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var rows = 1000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, rows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var subject = row[1];
    var message = row[2];
    var pdfName = row[3];
    var cc = row[4];
    var list = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName);

    if (list.hasNext()) {
      var File = list.next();
      GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, message, {
        cc: cc,
        attachments: [File]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About ``How to attach multiple files to individual drafts``, I cannot understand about what you want to do from your script. In your situation, there is one value in ``list`` at ``var list = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName)``. And there are several files with the same filename. Is my understanding correct? Can you provide the detail information about it? By getting the information, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: I would also like more info. What does it look like when are multiple files associated with one draft email? Are there multiple, comma-separated filenames in row 3?

Comment: Hi Tanaike and Dustin - thank you for your prompt response. I updated the post with more info and added a screenshot. Please let me know if theres anything else I can add.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for replying and adding more information. I noticed that an answer has already been posted just now. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** 
First off, I performed a `split()` on the values of the `pdfName` cell so I could search for and add one file at a time.

The draft creation would only run if there were files because it was inside the `list` if statement, no files meant it would not run.

I pulled it out of that and created [an interator for `list`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) and a files array that can be given to the `createDraft()` function. The iterator allows multiple Files to be added to the `files` array if the `DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName)` returns multiple Files.

```
function SaveDrafts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var rows = 1000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, rows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var subject = row[1];
    var message = row[2];
    var pdfName = row[3].split(','); //split the values taken from cell into array
    var cc = row[4];

    var files = []; //initialize files as empty array.

    for(var j in pdfName){ //run through cell values and perform search
      var results = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName[j]); //Perform the search,results is a FileIterator

      while(results.hasNext()) { //Interate through files found and add to attachment results
        files.push(results.next()); //Add files to array
      }
    }

    GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, message, {
      cc: cc,
      attachments: files //the attachments option takes our files array
    });

  }
}
```