# send mail with attachment in each row on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I use attachment in each cell to send mail auto.

## Note:

column 0: Firstname Column 4: Email Address Colum 5: Year Column 6: File Attachment.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

//Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
function autosendEmails() { 
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Your Sheet Id'); 
  var sheet= ws.getSheetByName('Mail Merge'); 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
  var numRows = ws.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process // Fetch the range of cells E2:H3 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // var FileID = DriveApp.getFileById('Your File Id')
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var row = data[i]; var emailAddress = row[4]; // First column
    var Subjectmail ="Test mail"
    var bodyemail = "Dear" 
    var pdfname = row[6]; 
    var emailSent = row[7]; // Four column 
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { 
      // Prevents sending duplicates 
      var subject = 'Test mail'; 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, Subjectmail, bodyemail, {attachments: pdfname}); 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration  you're retrieving the file name from  `var pdfname = row[6];` , then what you must do to attach the file to your mail and send it, it's to retrieve the actual file from your drive and putting it into an array as I did in this example:

```
// Inside your function, just change this line 
function autosendEmails() { 
...
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, Subjectmail, bodyemail, {
        attachments: buildAttachment(pdfname) // Call this function to be able to send an attachment file 
      }); 
...
}

// Add this function to your code
function buildAttachment(pdfname){
  // Initialize the array
  var fileArr = [];
  // Get the file form your drive
  var getMyFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfname).next();
  // build an array
  fileArr.push(getMyFile);
  // return the file within an array
  return fileArr;
}
```

### Reference

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948974/attach-multiple-files-google-sheets-gmail-drive) could help you, too.

### Docs

- [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

Answer (score 0):

This might work better for you:

Read the comments for explanation.

```
function autosendEmails() { 
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Your Sheet Id'); 
  var sheet= ws.getSheetByName('Mail Merge'); 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn());//you were missing your last column and you were grabbing an empty row and the end of your list because the third parameter is the number of rows in the data not the number of rows in the sheet.
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
    var row=data[i]; 
    var emailAddress = row[4]; // First column
    var Subjectmail ="Test mail"
    var bodyemail = "Dear" 
    var pdfname = row[6]; 
    var emailSent = row[7]; // Four column 
    if (emailSent !== "EMAIL_SENT") { 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, Subjectmail, bodyemail, {attachments: ["an array of files"]});//attachments should be an array of files not an array of filenames 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I normally use

```
function SendMailFC() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  
  var message ="HELLO" 
  for (var i = 2; i <= 3; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var mail = row[7];
    var name = row[4].substring(0,row[4].indexOf(" ",row[4].indexOf(" ")+1));
    var company = row[1].substring(0,row[1].indexOf(","));
    
    var Greeting = 'Hello ' + name+',<br><br>';
    var stat = row[10];
    
    var subject = "SUBJECT";
    if(stat){
      GmailApp.sendEmail(FROM, subject, "", {htmlBody: '<html>'+greeting+message+'</html>'} );
    }
  }
```